# Passing env variables to parent component from child component through props

Tags: reactjs, react-router, environment-variables, react-props

I am trying to create a contact form using emailjs and mailgun and i have added my credentials in a .env file and created the props in the child component where the env variables is supposed to be used. However in the parent component I am trying to pass the props from the child component using .

I have tried implementing the props in the contact form

**Contact.js**
This is the logic when the button is clicked

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

        const {
        REACT_APP_EMAILJS_RECEIVER: receiverEmail,
        REACT_APP_EMAILJS_TEMPLATEID: template
        } = this.props.env

    this.sendFeedback(
      template,
      this.sender,
      receiverEmail,
      this.state.feedback
    );

    this.setState({
      formSubmitted: true
    });
  }

sendFeedback(templateId, senderEmail, receiverEmail, feedback) {
    window.emailjs
      .send('mailgun', templateId, {
        senderEmail,
        receiverEmail,
        feedback
      })
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          formEmailSent: true
        });
      })
      // Handle errors here however you like
      .catch(err => console.error('Failed to send feedback. Error: ', err));
  }
```

**App.js**

```
  <Route exact path= '/contact' render={(props) => <Contact env = {props} />} />
```

The route I am trying to render the props

The expected output should render the props onto the parent component. I am quite new to React and love the simplicity of the library. A brief understanding of this concept and solution is expected. Thanks!

Comment: This is not the correct way of sending the env variables. Why do you suppose you are getting them in props? Have you tried console.log(props) either in the route or inside the component?

Comment: Yes! I have added a lifecycle hook `componentDidMount(process.env)` in App.js which shows the env variables in the console. A correct implementation of how i should send the props is then i would expect!